# How come changing "if else" code into a one-liner breaks it?

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

For this statement here, it works perfectly with the long version, but for the one-liner, it says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'". I kept the commands in the if statement the exact same and it doesn't seem like the syntax is the issue (since it's type error).
The all_lines is just provided as an example, though I've tried with other types of lists and they don't work with the one-liner either

Doesn't work:

```
all_lines = [["han"], ["and"], ['']]
for i, line in enumerate(all_lines):
    j += 1 if line == [''] else monkeys[j].append(line)
```

Works:

```
all_lines = [["han"], ["and"], ['']]
for i, line in enumerate(all_lines):
    if line == ['']:
        j += 1
    else:
        monkeys[j].append(line)
```

Comment: well, `append` returns `None` (i.e. it doesn't return anything that you can add, it just mutates a list), so in this case it does not make sense to put it in a if expression as such.

What is your actual goal for packing the lines? What do you want to achieve / why don't you keep the version that works?

Comment: try `(j := j+1) if line == [''] else monkeys[j].append(line)`

Comment: The one-liner does `j += monkeys[j].append(line)` in the _else_ case.

Answer (score 1):

Because the ternary conditional applies to the expression after `+=`, not to the entire line. In other words, your attempt translates to

```
# BUG: adding the wrong thing
for i, line in enumerate(all_lines):
    if line == ['']:
        what = 1
    else:
        what = monkeys[j].append(line)
    j += what
```

If you really insist on using a ternary conditional, perhaps try something like

```
for line in all_lines:
    j += 1 if line == "" else monkeys[j].append(line) or 0
```

though the longhand certainly seems preferable for legibility as well as pythonicity.

In your example data, the elements of `all_lines` are lists, not strings, so the condition will never be true. Did you perhaps mean to check for equivalence to the list `['']`, or to loop over the individual list subelements; or for the list to contain strings?

Answer (score 1):

What your short version is actually doing is the following:

```
all_lines = [["han"], ["and"], ['']]
for i, line in enumerate(all_lines):
    if line == ['']:
        j += 1
    else:
        j += monkeys[j].append(line)
```

so in the else part you are trying to add the return value of List.append() which is None, hence you get a TypeError.
From the snippet you provided it is a bit difficult to see what you are trying to achieve. It seems you are not using the counter of enumerate (i) so you may as well remove enumerate.